# Rotate SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an ULTRALEGACY db where, for unknown reasons (to me), parameters tables are structured like this:

```
|Parameter1|Parameter2|Parameter3|Parameter4 ...
------------------------------------------------
|  Value1  |  Value2  |  Value3  |  Value4   ...
```

dozens and dozens of columns and a single values row (yeah, makes no sense for me either)

How can I query those tables for a result like

```
|Parameter|Value |
-----------------
|param1   |value1|
|param2   |value2|
|param3   |value3|
...
```

I just managed to get the first column with

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME as Parameter
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='parameter_table_name'
```

but I can't figure out how to get value columns, I guess I have to pivot the table but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Try PIVOT to transform the table

Comment: How many columns are there, and do you expect the number of columns to vary at all?

Comment: @DineshDB read last line :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen columns number vary from table to table (yeah, there's more of this s***) and i'm trying to find a silver-bullet-query which suits every table structured like this

Comment: You need unpivot rather than pivot

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `UNPIVOT`.

My example is for fixed number of columns, if it's variable you need to use `dynamic sql` to get the list of them and to construct `UNPIVOT` statement.

```
declare @t table (p1 int, p2 int, p3 int);
insert into @t values(1, 2, 3);

select param, val
from @t unpivot (val for param in (p1, p2, p3))u;
```

Comment: nice! how can i cope with different column types? i don't mind to cast all as varchar

Comment: If there are at least 2 columns of different types that cannot be converted to the same type you should convert all your columns to varchars.

Comment: SQL_VARIANT is an option too, but it is not recognized by all clients and will require extra efforts to handle it properly in later stages.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to use `cross apply`

```
select a.* from <table> t
cross apply(
            values ('param1', t.Parameter1),
                   ('param2', t.Parameter2),
                   ('param3', t.Parameter3),
                   ('param4', t.Parameter4)
         ) a(Parameter, Value)
```

Result :

```
Parameter   Value
param1      Value1
param2      Value2
param3      Value3
param4      Value4
```

Comment: great, i have A LOT of columns and names vary from table to table, so i can't type them all